# STOMP vs WAMP over Spring-WebSockets

Tags: java, wamp, stomp, spring-websocket

I am currently working on a project that needs to work with WebSockets.
The clients will be the browsers only, so not interested in any message broker feature of these two.

Although I don't think that it would be much a difference, but would be interested if I can get a few comments on [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/) vs [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) as a subprotocol using Spring-WebSockets.

And I might get a few hints that may help choose one over the other.

Cheers,

**EDITED (27-02-2014):**
As, programming directly with webSockets is low-level, so its suggested in many places (one the spring documentation) to use some sub-protocol.

Also, the use of a sub-protocol over websocket, is a type of native webSocket security; like you can do a sub-protocol validation.

There are many other sub-protocol that can be used instead of STOMP or WAMP like XMPP, AMQP.
I couldn't find much information related to these and webSockets, most of it is related to message brokers only.

Comment: Not really a question for this site, try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I am writing a server in Java, don't think serverfault.com is the right place. This is a proper design/programming question. Please read through spring documentation and if you still believe this to be moved then do vote for REST vs SOAP questions to be moved as well.

Comment: Maybe not, but this is not the right place either. This if for people having a problem with a specific small piece of code they can show and describe there problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one reason (obvious) that I should use STOMP over any other sub-protocol, is that I am using spring-webSockets so for STOMP I don't need add any additional library at the server side, for others I would need to.
At the clients there are many JS libraries that I can use like socket.io for STOMP and similar JS for WAMP and others.

Since, my main concern is at the server side: So, STOMP it is.

I will update this post if I find out something new while implementing my solution.

Comment: i've been looking at similar options. Would love to hear about your experience